# Suppose $x$ and $y$ are any two points in a metric space $(X,d)$. Let $r$ and $R$ be two positive numbers. Show that

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

The question is the following

> Suppose $x$ and $y$ are any two points in a metric space $(X,d)$. Let
>   $r$ and $R$ be two positive numbers. Show that
>
> (a) If $d(x,y) \geq R+r$, then the open balls $B_R(x)$ and $B_r(y)$ are disjoint.
>
> (b) If $d(x,y) \leq R-r$, then $B_r(y) \subseteq B_R(x)$.
>
> (c) The converse statements to (a) and (b) are not always true (give counterexamples).

I did complete the first two questions, but I have no idea abou the part (c). Can anyone give any help? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the discrete metric on a set $X$ with at least two points. Then $B_1(x)\cap B_1(y)$ is empty whenever $x \neq y$ but $d(x,y) = 1 <1+1$ so the converse of a) is not true.

Also note that $B_2(x) \subseteq B_{1.5}(x)$ for any $x$ but $0=d(x,x) \leq 1.5-2=-0.5$ is f alse. Hence the converse of b) is also false.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! But I don't understand how the second one works. As far as I know, $B_2(x)$ in the discrete metric is the entire set $X$, and $B_1(x)$ stands for the single point $\{x\}$. Why are you saying that $B_2(x) \subseteq B_1(x)$?

Comment: @UnbelieveTable Sorry, there was  a mistake. I have edited my answer now.

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense